# Power Bi Axis X and Y

Tags: histogram, powerbi

I am new on power Bi 
I want to create an Histogram and define Axis :

> X -> Function (Term, R&D...)
>     Y-> Method (Cost , benef...)
>     Value _> Sum(amount )

And in each Method have a vertical Histogram 
I dont see where can I define Axis X and Y to build my Histogram 
In Tableau Software and Spotfire I can define several dimension in the column 
but not in Power BI

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you give the [histogram custom visual](https://app.powerbi.com/visuals/show/Histogram1445664487616) at try?